# Print definition of functions of user created Mathematica Packages

Tags: packages

To expedite the work I do I have created a Mathematica Package that has all the functions I need to plot the data I need to analyze.

The problem is every now and then I will need to slightly modify one of the functions and will need to go and look for the `.m` package, copy the function onto the notebook, change the name, and work from there. I was wondering if there is any way that I could create a function inside the Package that would print the contents of the functions so I don't have to lose time searching. Something like `PrintFunPac[Function1]` that would return the definition of `Function1`.

Tried googling and didn't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always enter

```
?? <packagename>`*
```

where `<packagename>` is the name of the package/context you want to inspect.

For example

```
?? Developer`*
```

contains many useful symbols.

For deeper hidden symbols, you can also try

```
?? <packagename>`*`*
```

Another helpful tool is hidden in the package `` "GeneralUtilities`" ``. Run the following and be amazed:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[HoldPrint];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!.  The first thing you said `?? <packagename>`*  ` did return the definition of the functions but with the ``packagename`Private` `` in front of the variables' name, but your solution of ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[HoldPrint];`` worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @M.O. I think it is not clear what is the goal. Your question suggested you want to access the code and edit it but `PrintDefinitions` creates notebooks that are not ready to play with. Or is preview code the main goal?

Comment: @Kuba, I thought I had been pretty straightforward but I guess not. The package I have created is done, but as the input data changes and the images are needed for different purposes, every now and then I need to change the functions of the package a bit. I was asking a way to get the definition of the function of my package, meaning the code, from mathematica instead of searching for the `.m`, copying the function, pasting it in the `.nb`, changing its name and then make the changes. Using `Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[HoldPrint];` as Henrik suggested did just that.

Comment: @M.O. That is what I thought too, but then `PrintDefinitions`, for me at least, generates notebook with interactive (Tooltips/Hyperlinks) symbols that are not just a plain code you can slightly edit and evaluate.

Comment: But one can "copy as input". Still a bit annoying, but it is still better than searching for the source file...

Comment: Yeah, you can copy it as `plain text` and it works.`input text` for me adds the public names of the functions with the name of the package added to it, so for what I need copying as `plain text` works perfectly.

Comment: @M.O. Huh! Yeah, that works. Great! So I also learned something here! =D