# How can we create a FunctionQ function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-test

How can we check if an entry to our function is a `Function` or a `Pure Function`?

For example:

```
FunctionQ[target_]:=...

FunctionQ[Function[x, x^2]] == True
FunctionQ[#^2&] == True
FunctionQ[x^2] == False
```

It looks like we don't have a `FunctionQ` method available on Mathematica.

The motivation is that I'd like to combine [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223407/how-can-we-create-functions-like-mathematica-does) with the answer of this question to create only one function for the accepted answer of that link.

**Edit**:

Combining the provided answer, it looks like we can do the following:

```
FunctionQ[expression_Function?System`Private`ValidQ] := True;
FunctionQ[___] := False;
Test[expression_, variable_Symbol] :=
  Block[
    {final},
    If[
     FunctionQ[expression],
     final = expression,
     final = Function[variable, expression]
     ]
    ][4];

Test[Function[x, x^2], x] (* 1 *)

Test[#^2 &, x] (* 2 *)

Test[x^2, x] (* 3 *)

f1 = x^2; Test[f1, x] (* 4 *)

f2[x_] := x^2; Test[f2, x] (* 5 *)

Test[f2[x], x] (* 6 *)


16 (* 1 *)

16 (* 2 *)

16 (* 3 *)

16 (* 4 *)

b (* 5 *)

16 (* 6 *)
```

Comment: Should `FunctionQ[Log]` return `True`? How about `FunctionQ[Derivative[1][Zeta]]` or `FunctionQ[Hold]`?

Comment: Interesting point. I'll check this more in depth and return.

Comment: For explicit functions (i.e., have the `Head` of `Function`) you can use a pattern like `f[z_Function] := ...`. Then `f[(#^2&)]` or `f[Function[{x},x^2]]` would evaluate.

Comment: Hum, this is interesting as well.

Comment: @GarouDan Out of curiosity, this and your other previous questions seemed to point to some odd requirements in your code. Since I have made the mistake of concentrating on fixing my proposed solution rather than refactoring the problem (a classic XY Problem), I like to ask: What is the final ultimate goal here? I.e. why do you need the functionality you are developing? I don't mean to say that there is anything wrong with your approach, it's just that one sometimes gets bogged down in the details of implementing the first solution that comes up, rather than thinking whether it is the best one.

Comment: maple has this build in actually. There is specific type called `function`. [check type for function](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type%2Ffunction) it is useful for parsing input for example. Mathematica should really have **FunctionQ** as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observing the fact that valid `Function` objects seem to be marked as `ValidQ` we can use

```
FunctionQ[f_Function?System`Private`ValidQ] := True
FunctionQ[___] := False
```

Then use it via

```
In[100]:= FunctionQ[Function[{x, y}, x + 2]]

Out[100]= True

In[103]:= FunctionQ[# + 1 &]

Out[103]= True

In[105]:= FunctionQ[Log]

Out[105]= False

In[106]:= FunctionQ[Function[]]

During evaluation of In[106]:= Function::argb: Function called with 0 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.

Out[106]= False
```

Comment: Oh, cool, clever solution. I'll check and return ;)

Comment: I think for my purposes it works fine ;), only one case above didn't work (please see my edit). If you know how could I solve it, please let me know ;)

Comment: One other thing that I'd like to ask. How did you find about `System`Private`ValidQ`? I'd like to use this approach to find how the things are defined in Mathematica in the future?

Comment: @GarouDan you can use techniques such as ``Names[“System`*”]`` or related to find those sorts of things. Also try searching “spelunking tools” in the search bar here. And looking into the developer tools would be helpful, too.

Comment: @CATrevillian, unfortunately `Names[“System`*”]` does not contain any reference to `ValidQ`. Also using the Mathematica search nothing appears. About searching here, I tried "spelunking tools" and it seems interesting, but I didn't find yet a place with a collection of these kind of tools to use. It would be very useful for me.

Comment: @GarouDan try exploring the private context, so using ``”System`Private`*”`` within `Names`. I had given the truncated example in an attempt to be generalized, and also laziness when responding on mobile. As for using the search in the documentation center, I doubt you would find something of the nature of `ValidQ`. However, you might find some useful information using the developer tools to print the definition of the function/symbol/context you are interested in.

Comment: @GarouDan my deepest apologies. You want to use ``”GeneralUtilities`”`` within `Needs`, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/181779/63039).

Comment: Indeed this is very interesting, we can get a lot of insights. But it still a mystery for me how @JsonB was able to find the ValidQ from the functions definitions. Specially when he says: `Observing the fact that valid Function objects seem to be marked as ValidQ we can use`

Comment: Search this site for `ValidQ`.  People share insights here, which come from a variety of sources.  I learned about `ValidQ` from a post on this site.