# Is there a way which allows getting the code of commands from contributed packages?

Tags: programming, packages

I guess  there is some simple  way for getting the code of commands from contributed packages.  Is there a specific command for that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? isn't the code of the package available in the package files? or do you mean just print  the definition of a function in a package?  if so, see [print-definition-of-functions-of-user-created-mathematica-packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181778/print-definition-of-functions-of-user-created-mathematica-packages)

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks :)